# two weeks after interview

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I applied for a position online, and got a call from the HR manager from the head office three days after for a telephone interview. This went well and two days after I was invited for a face to face interview.
I was interviwed by two senior staff members, with one person in the room and the other on a conference call from the head office.
In my opinion the interview went well and the interviewer present told me after the interview I did well, and that I should hear back the following week as they have more people to interview. (I was the first person to be interviewed).

They told me a lot about the company, the training offered and all, I was am positive about the role.

I sent a thank you note to the HR Manager at the head office and reiterated my interest, she replied saying they are pleased I am still interested and would get back to me the week after.

Two weeks have passed with no update and I noticed the position has been re-advertised online. I decided to send a short email to the HR asking for an update and I got a reply almost immediately saying:

*Hi,

Hope you are well.

We were impressed with you but we have not yet reached a final decision. It will take a few more weeks and I'll inform you.

Thank you so much for your patience.*

Do you think I'm still in with any chance of getting a positive feedback considering the fact that the role has been re-advertised?

I am really interested in the role and the wait is kind of killing me.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, I really appreciate you taking your time to reply.
I have started searching for some other job as it sounds like im just an alternative and no one likes to be treated as such. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer - **You still have a chance**.

Based on the multiple interviews you went through, and them telling you that they were impressed, then I'd say you're still a top contender.

They did state, however, that you were the first interviewed.  I wouldn't be surprised if it took a couple of months for them to get back to you on the decision.  Ultimately, the hiring manager makes the decision - and HR doesn't know when that decision is going to come.  The hiring manager may decide to interview a few more candidates whose resumes have impressed them, or interview every candidate that they get a resume on.

It's also possible that you are either under-qualified(but impressive) or over-qualified for the position - I don't know your skillset - and they may be interviewing to see if they can find a better fit.  If not, you still have a chance at securing the job.

Either way, I would suggest sending a hand-written thank you note to the senior members/hiring manager that interviewed you.  While sending a card/note to HR is fine, sending one to the hiring manager is going to keep your name in their mind. Also, do not send gifts.  Most companies have policies regarding not receiving gifts in these situations.

**Personal Experience**

Every company has different hiring processes.  For example, the company I'm currently with took nearly 5 months from the initial phone interview, to having a contract that I could sign and officially call me apart of the company.  My previous employer only took about 3 weeks from initial interview to signing on. It's different everywhere you go, never count yourself out unless you know for sure you're not getting it.

Answer (score 2):

Combined with the re-advertisement,

> Hi, Hope you are well. We were impressed with you but we have not yet reached a final decision. It will take a few more weeks and i'll inform you. Thank you so much for your patience.

Reads to me as: "While you were competent, we think we can do better (and will be interviewing other candidates). If we can't find anyone better, we might settle for you. Please don't be mad."

There are certainly other possible reasons (hiring manager had a car accident, waiting on budget, the person you were going to replace decided to return, bureaucracy) I would not wait for this company to continue your job search.

Comment: I think the last statement is the most important: `I would not wait for this company to continue your job search` Is there ever a reason to wait? Until you get a concrete offer, and at that point there's no more neet to "wait".

Answer (score 0):

I have been in this situation both at the receiving end and the decision making process.

I wouldnt send a 'thank you' note again as you could come off as someone who really wants this job and is desperate to get it. This can work against you while negotiating the package.

In my experience its better to keep looking elsewhere as most of the times it unfortunately is not a good news. The team is in two minds and if they find someone better they will go with them...you are basically on stand-by. And you dont want to waste your time in the meantime.

It could in some cases also mean that the position is on hold for whatever reasons (budget or other issues).

Goodluck!